# Can't access the interface method from Rhino mock stub

Tags: rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mock for my unit testing in my webapp using ASP.NET MVC and C#. I'm have a problem creating stubs in one of my method in the service interface. That method is returning a class. Please kindly see below the code,

The class of the Model Acct

```
public class Acct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Acct GetAcct( string user )
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Interface for Account

```
public interface IAccount
{
    Acct GetAcct( string user );
}
```

Account service that will access the method from the model class above,

```
public class Account : IAccount
{
    public Acct GetAcct( string user )
    {
       retrun Acct.GetAcct( user );
    }
}
```

Then I can't access the GetAcct method of Account service class when I want to create a stub.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you stubbing the class instead of the interface?

Answer (score 1):

The GetAcct method on Account must be virtual if you want a mocking framework (like Rhino.Mocks, moq, etc...) to be able to mock it.